# How to create Hierarchical RelativeLayouts programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am new in android and I have done so much googling for this issue. Actually I want to create below UI in Code of android:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_background">

       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/event_1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/color_001">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_event_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="j1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a quick example code based on your xml layout. I tried make it clear by using comments but if you don't understand something, I can try to explain it a little more.

```
// Creating the outer RelativeLayout which has id "relativeLayout2" in your xml layout.
RelativeLayout outerRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);

// ------------------------------------------------------------------

// Creating the inner RelativeLayout which has id "event_1" in your xml layout.
RelativeLayout innerRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);

// Creating the TextView which has id "txt_event_1" in your xml layout.
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
textView.setText("j1");

// Defining the layout parameters of the TextView
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
textViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

// Adding the TextView to the inner RelativeLayout as a child
innerRelativeLayout.addView(textView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

// ------------------------------------------------------------------

// Adding the inner RelativeLayout to the outer RelativeLayout as a child
outerRelativeLayout.addView(innerRelativeLayout, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(convertDptoPx(40), convertDptoPx(40)));

// ------------------------------------------------------------------

// Defining the layout parameters of the outer RelativeLayout
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rootParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rootParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

// Set the layout parameters associated with the outer RelativeLayout.
outerRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(rootParams);
```

Although this code snippet doesn't include some of the xml attributes defined in your xml layout, you can find the related methods in the documentation of the view.

For instance, if you look at the TextView documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), you can see the "XML Attributes" table which shows the attribute name and related method.

Answer (score 1):

use this code.

```
RelativeLayout layout1= new RelativeLayout(this);
LayoutParams param1= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

RelativeLayout layout2= new RelativeLayout(this);
LayoutParams param2= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView text= new TextView(this);
text.setText("your text");
layout2.addView(text, param2);

layout1.addView(layout2, param1);
setContentView(layout1);
```

Comment: your ans is nice....... but now what should i do if i want to keep my outter relative layout(android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2") in xml and need to make inner relative layout and textivew from code ?

Comment: when i m doing like this : RelativeLayout layout1= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);                           RelativeLayout layout2= new RelativeLayout(this);
   LayoutParams param2= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   TextView text= new TextView(this);
   text.setText("your text");
   layout2.addView(text, param2);

   layout1.addView(layout2);
   setContentView(layout1);                    it giving me error :       

you must call removeview() on the child's parent first

Answer (score 1):

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams childVw = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
    TextView textVw = new TextView(this);
    textVw.setLayoutParams(childVw);
```

Then add this to your main relative layout

Answer (score 1):

```
 setContentView(R.layout.layoutfilename);


    RelativeLayout layout1= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourlayoutid);
    LayoutParams param1= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    RelativeLayout layout2= new RelativeLayout(this);
    LayoutParams param2= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView text= new TextView(this);
    text.setText("your text");
    layout2.addView(text, param2);


    layout1.addView(layout2);
```